# Mock PUT request using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine, ngresource

The declaration of the User resource would be something like:

```
factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/user/:userId.json', {}, {
        put: {method:'PUT', params: {userId:'@id'}},
    });
})
```

As you can see the -default- parameter for the PUT method is the id attribute within the resource.

if you would like to test:

```
httpBackend.expectPUT('api/user/1.json').respond(200);
userResource.put();
httpBackend.flush();
```

I keep getting a failure in the test cause the actual URL that it's being generated is: 'api/user/.json'. The id attribute is not being included in the URL.

It makes sense because I haven't specified the id attribute to the mock object, I didn't because I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `userResource.put({id:1});`

Comment: @Chandermani That isn't necessary if `userResource` is an instance of `User`.  It does require, however, that `userResource` has an `id` property set to `1` at the time `put()` is called.  Did you set that up in the test?

Comment: On a related but separate note, you may be interested in reading my article: http://kirkbushell.me/angular-js-using-ng-resource-in-a-more-restful-manner/

It provides a way of using ngResource in a way that follows RESTful conventions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path should start with '/', and you need to pass in an ID to make the path match with what is generated in your code. The URL match is string match, so you need to guarantee the URL you expect to hit is exactly same as what is generated.

```
httpBackend.expectPUT('/api/user/1.json').respond(200);
userResource.put({id:1});
httpBackend.flush();
```